# Loading image icon with JavaFX is causing jar file to not display

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar, interface

When running my code in Eclipse, the interface and functionality works as expected. When exported to a jar, the interface will not show up if the commented line of code that loads the icon is included.

Relevant code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    try
    {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Display.fxml"));
      Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
      primaryStage.setTitle("Bill Pay Refund Generator");
      ((Controller) loader.getController()).setStage(primaryStage);
      //primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/cc16.png")));
      primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The resources folder that includes the image is inside of the project bin folder.

This is the stack trace when running the jar from command line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1128)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:706)
        at application.Main.start(Main.java:36)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit: On catching the exception, the window displays, but without the icon showing. I guess the more general question is where exactly do I need to save my resource images?

Comment: `getClass().getResource("Display.fxml")` looks for a Display.fxml in the *same package* as your class.

Comment: The Display.fxml is working fine. Only when loading the image icon is there any problems.

Comment: Oh, right, my mistake;  the issue is with `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/cc16.png")`.  Is the `resources` directory in the same place as Display.fxml?

Comment: inside of my `bin` folder I have two folders. One is `application`, the other is `resources`. The fxml file is inside of the application folder, and the pictures are inside the resources folder.

Comment: The .fxml file is technically a resource.  Since you can read that file successfully, I would move the image to the same place, then let your code retrieve it with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("cc16.png")`.  Alternatively, you can add the `resources` directory to your project’s list of packaged directories (in which case Display.fxml probably ought to be moved into resources).

Comment: It is reading the input stream as null even in the IDE when I try it like that.